# ASP.Net MVC returns 404 for URLs with Action parameters but not for default route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using a WebForms application with some MVC components added in. The idea is to move more and more of the app over to MVC but there is no way it can be transitioned all at once. For various reasons I cannot control it must use ASP.Net 2.0 and MVC 2.0 since those are what ship built-in. I must also support IIS 6 and IIS 7.

First, I am well aware of the problems with extensionless routing and I am *not* attempting to use it so there are no issues with wildcard mappings, etc. I first attempted to use my routes ala "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}" but after banging my head on the wall I switched to "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}" but am having the same issues.

Second, I cannot get this to work even in IIS 7 Integrated mode on my dev machine, let alone Classic mode or IIS 6. It all runs correctly under Cassini but once I deploy to IIS 7 the MVC components break. Since this is on my dev machine I know ASP.Net is registered with IIS correctly and I can see all the inherited HTTP handlers in the control panel (eg: ASPX maps to PageHandlerFactory).

**Symptoms**:
All ASPX WebForms requests work perfectly.
An MVC requests to *just* the controller with no action/id specified get routed to MVC and execute properly as well.
*Any request to an MVC route with an action or id immediately returns a 404*. It is as if IIS thinks the ".mvc" extension is part of the folder path so it ignores the HTTP handler and returns a 404.

In other words:
/app/WebForm.aspx - *HTTP 200 OK, executes WebForm.aspx.cs code-behind*
/app/Fancy.mvc - *HTTP 200 OK, executes /Controllers/FancyController.cs, Index method*
/app/Fancy.mvc/DoThingy - *HTTP 404 NOT FOUND, even though FancyController has DoThingy method*

**Bad Solutions**: I have tried things like setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests but not only is that bad for performance it also breaks my Web Forms as well. Even when I set it to ignore all routes with .ASPX in them they still break.

I cannot use wildcard mapping so that is no help.

**Other Details**:
I setup my HTTP Handler in web.config/system.WebServer. It is the first handler listed.

```
<add name="MvcRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

It doesn't seem to matter what handler I specify or what options - IIS just doesn't seem to be examining any of this configuration (again because it seems to think the Fancy.mvc part of the path is a directory name, doesn't find that directory, then bails).

My routes:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspq/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("Default",
               "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
               new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
               );
```

**Update:** I tried using IIS 7 Classic mode; I then added a .mvc mapping in the IIS Manager pointing at the asp_net ISAPI dll and got the same result

Answer (score 1):

OK just so others don't look foolish, it turns out that this was a problem with URLs... the URL was being sent to the root of the site, not the app directory. I should have checked that to begin with. I didn't think this was the problem because when I manually typed the URL into the address bar it worked on the Index but the action method required HttpPost, so it was a combination of factors that made the script and manually-entered addresses spit out the same error message.

For anyone else mixing WebForms and MVC, double and triple-check that your URLs are correct. Here is some code I am *now* using on the WebForms master page so my client-side JS can know where to route MVC requests:

```
string baseUrl =  Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
if (baseUrl.EndsWith("/")) baseUrl = baseUrl.Substring(0, baseUrl.Length - 1);
baseUrl = baseUrl + ResolveUrl("~/");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("BaseUrl", baseUrl);
```